# COM interop marshalling error on IPersistStream Save

Tags: c#, marshalling, com-interop

I'm working on a Windows Explorer extension with two toolbars (I didn't write the original code), that uses the definition for IPersistStream and BandObject found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2219/Extending-Explorer-with-Band-Objects-using-NET-and). When I attach to Explorer using VS 2010, I get the following error:

> Managed Debugging Assistant 'InvalidMemberDeclaration' has detected a problem in 'C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe'.
>
> Additional Information: The following error occurred while determining how to marshal the parameters of member 'Save' of type 'BandObjectLib.IPersistStream': System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException: Cannot marshal 'return value': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination (Int/UInt must be paired with SysInt or SysUInt). This is most likely due to an incompatible MarshalAs attribute on one of the parameters.

I assume this means there is some mismatch between the C# method signature:

```cs
//(no PersistSig)
void Save([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IntPtr pStm, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool fClearDirty);
```

and the expected signature for IPersistStream::Save:

```
HRESULT Save(
  [in]  IStream *pStm,
  [in]  BOOL fClearDirty
);
```

The implementation of this method in the implementing class looks like this:

```cs
public virtual void Save(IntPtr pStm, bool fClearDirty) {}
```

A complete answer would be good, but any ideas as to how I can debug and solve this would also be helpful (please keep in mind that I have a minimal and very theoretical understanding of COM interop).